# Uniswap V3 Liquidity NFT value estimation

Tags: ethereum, uniswap

I want to build Uniswap V3 LPs staking platform, I have a few questions regarding this
How can I determine the worth of the staked NFT?
How can I get the total liquidity of that pool?
And I want to do all of this via smart contract, can anyone help me out with this?

[Source: Uniswap Blog](https://blog.uniswap.org/uniswap-v3-math-primer-2)

[Liquidity NFT image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQydA.png)

thanks for the help...

To get the estimate value of LP NFT in smart contract.